# Python - Float Division by Zero?

Tags: python

So I'm writing this code for my class and I encountered one error that with it which im not sure why it is returning an error. 
This is the section of code that returns this error:

```
    numValues = int(input("Input number of inputs (between 1 and 15): "))
    newList = []


    def input_nums():
        inputs = float(input("Enter a float value: "))
        newList.append(inputs)
        return newList


    while numValues:
        input_nums()
        numValues -= 1


    def in_order():
        for i in newList:
            print(i)


    def rev_order():
        for j in newList[::-1]:
            print(j)


    def abo_bel_equ():
        avg = sum(newList) / numValues ## This line gives the error ##
        print("The average is: ", avg)
        for x in range(numValues):
            above_avg = below_avg = equal_avg = 0
            if newList[x] > avg:
                above_avg += 1
            if newList[x] < avg:
                below_avg += 1
            if newList[x] == avg:
                equal_avg += 1


    print("The values of the list in order are: ")
    in_order()
    print("The values of the list in reverse order are: ")
    rev_order()
    print(abo_bel_equ())
```

The 'numValues' variable should be whatever integer the user entered, but instead returns 0.

Why is this function saying the numValues variable is zero when it should be the users input integer?

Comment: why don't you try adding a `if ` statement to check the value of `numValues`

Comment: From this code itself, there should be no issue unless the user inputs '0'. Could we see more of the code?

Comment: I tes this code ,there is no error.

Comment: Yes ill just paste my whole code, 1 second. (updated)

Comment: @LukeH. Put `numValues = len(newList)` at the top of `abo_bel_equ()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously suggested by Javier Lim, you could rewrite the while statement to work with a temporary variable, but you could also change

```
avg = sum(newList) / numValues
```

to be

```
avg = sum(newlist) / len(newList)
```

so that you don't have to include extra variables. This seems possible to me because, as it looks from your code, `newlist` must always have a length that is equal to `numValues`.

Comment: Yeah, I totally overlooked this, and it does indeed work. Thanks! By the way, I'm trying to get the above,below, and equal to avg part of the function to work but it doesnt seem to work right. Any idea how I can make that work?

Comment: Well, first of all the parameter of the range is also set to `numValues`, so that should be changed to len(newList) as well. Secondly, I would recommend to use `elif`-statements here. In your current code, these three checks will be executed every time, even if the value is indeed above average. So `elif` will prevent that. And lastly, it is in my opinion a good idea to return these three values (if these comparisons are the objective of the function of course).

Comment: As a second note, you could even use the fact that a boolean is equivalent with an integer (`True == 1` and `False == 0`). In python 3 and python 2.6 the equivalence is guaranteed. So statements like `a = b > c` are perfectly valid. And also `a += b > c` could be used in your case.

Comment: I see. Well I got them to print out anyway just by changing the parameter like you said and where I set them = 0. So I could keep them like that, but I'm confused what you meant by using a+= b > c

Comment: In python, a Boolean is equivalent with an integer . If you would for example try to run the code `print(5 + True)` the output will be `6`, so if you want to check if the value in the list is greater than the average, you could just write `above_avg += newList[x] > avg`.

Comment: Ohh okay I see what you mean. It does work fine either way so I think I'll just leave them in the if/elif statements for now because that was the way my instructor wants. Thanks for your help with this though! It means alot

Answer (score 0):

This is the error.

```
   while numValues:
        input_nums()
        numValues -= 1
```

this will remove 1 from numValues until it is 0, then break out.
use

```
for i in range(numValues):
    input_nums()
```

or this, if a while loop is needed.

```
temp = numValues
while temp:
    input_nums()
    temp -= 1
```

Comment: That is part of my assignment though, my teacher wanted us to use a while loop to get the inputs from the user. How can I rewrite the while loop to not break it out to zero?

Comment: Sure, new solution added.